# xarray - Calculating intramonthly mean

Tags: python, mean, netcdf, python-xarray

I have several netcdf files, which I have opened with xarray. They contain daily data from 1950 to date.
What I want to do is to calculate the intramonthly mean, that means the mean from Jan 15 - Feb 15, Feb 16 - March 15 and so on.

I tried using  `ds.shift` like this:

```
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('F:/PPT_Int*.nc',combine = 'by_coords', concat_dim="time")

AA = ds.shift(time = 15) 
temp_m = AA.resample(time="1MS", skipna = False).mean()
```

But I'm unsure if it's a correct approach. I don't know if there's and option with `resample` that will do this.